# How to change bitrate of audio file to 32kbps in android

Tags: android, audio, mp3

I want to compress audio and have found the only solution is to use ffmpeg.

I have tried to use FFMPEG for android. It is compiling but still not working, I'm not able to get how it compiled.

I have no knowledge about FFMPEG and i use Continuousaudiorecorder for this.

Comment: https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

compile group: 'com.github.hoary.ffmpeg', name: 'FFmpeg-android-arm', version: '2.0.1.1'

visit above link and refer this may be helpful to you